# Exception ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument out of the range of valid values.at Azure.HttpRange..ctor(Int64 offset, Nullable`1 length)

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-.net

**Platform:**
.Net

**Version:**
[image]

**Code:**
[image]

**Error:**
[image]

Anything which I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
using (var content = new MemoryStream(buffer)){}
```

I needed to use buffer as above in the MemoryStream.